# Where is "http://ubuntu/ubuntu" (in apt sources.list) defined?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

In recent servers provided by my client's hosting provider, the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file contains references to:

```
deb http://ubuntu/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
...
deb http://ubuntu-secu/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

while previous servers contained lines that I'm used to see:

```
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
...
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse
```

This particular url doesn't seem to resolve, yet the upgrades seem to work.

Is this something provided by Ubuntu itself?

If not, what is the explanation and where can it likely be defined?

Comment: I'd rather expect that this is something provided by your hosting provider, and it only resolves inside their network.

Comment: I though about that, but `curl -I http://ubuntu` gives `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ubuntu`, same for `dig`. I'm puzzled at this point!

Comment: You did not disclose if it doesn't resolve on your server or on your local machine, so the option was still possible.

Comment: It's buried in the middle of the text, sorry about that! But thanks for the suggestion! (EDIT: I understand you now!)

Comment: Thanks again for your comment, this helped me find the right direction!

Answer (score 4):

I think I found out: the provider has set up an apt proxy in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
Acquire::http {
          Proxy "http://xxx.the-provider.com:1234";
};
```

This seems to understand the `http://ubuntu/ubuntu`.

Thanks to https://serverfault.com/users/38644/gerald-schneider for the hint!

Comment: Nice finding. I didn't think about a proxy, although I'm using one myself inside our network.

Comment: Well thanks a lot to you - without your suspicion on the provider, I wouldn't have digged necessarily in that direction. Many thanks!

Comment: As [Ubuntu does not notice stale proxies by default](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/716535), you probably want to configure appropriate `valid-until-max` for such apt-sources.